# Knockout Posting nested (master detail) form without ajax (Normal form post)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, master-detail

i have just gone through knockoutjs and watched the video provided on the [site](http://knockoutjs.com/). its quite interesting how we can cleanly arrange our js code using knockout. I have also gone through examples where it produces nested or master detail forms but these forms are always submitted through ajax. Is there a way i can post the nested form without ajax without breaking asp.net mvc's default modelbinding. More specifically i want the behavior as in this [code demo](http://www.esnips.com/doc/943ed057-7d97-4c2c-b5fe-0ab185c3828d/MasterDetail-v-2) that [i created a while ago](http://zahidadeel.blogspot.com/2011/05/master-detail-form-in-aspnet-mvc-3-ii.html). but now i want to do it using knockoutjs and without ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the answer to this question: [Submit json to MVC3 action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036297/submit-json-to-mvc3-action/6036596#6036596)

It describes using the utility function  `ko.utils.postJson` to submit part or all of your view model using a normal form post.  It does require an attribute on the .NET side to properly deserialize it from a form post (as opposed to using AJAX with the content type set to JSON).

Also, check out this thread for some ideas if you need to mix Knockout data with normal form fields: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/knockoutjs/eCQo4yzCSAc/discussion  and this thread also describes registering a model binder for certain types, so you don't need to use an attribute: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/knockoutjs/3FEpocpApA4/discussion

So, your best bet is to look at calling `ko.utils.postJson(url, ko.toJSON(viewModel))`

Comment: thanks RP this is exactly what i was looking for. Any thoughts how mvc's server side validation play nicely with knockout

Comment: I think that getting DataAnnotations on your model to flow into client-side validation for Knockout is a bit of a challenge for dynamic content (like collections) at the moment.  You would need to generate your template, such that the elements had the proper class/data- attributes on them and use a technique like the `parseDynamicContent` function that was shown in your link.  That is something that I have been meaning to play with a bit.

Comment: That would be great. Is there any place i can follow the progress on your game play. May be i will be able to contribute a little bit

Comment: If I do have something to share, it would probably be on my blog http://knockmeout.net or on the KO forums: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/knockoutjs.  Feel free to join or create discussions on topics like this there.  Good luck!

Comment: i have already joined you people on google group this morning:) thanks for the link however

Comment: Great, looking forward to your help and ideas!

Comment: @RP any ideas on how can i change name generation of input fields in knockoutjs without changing the code of library itself

Comment: Are you talking about inside ko.utils.postJson or just generally?  You can use the `attr` binding to control the name, if you like.  Something like: `data-bind="attr: { name: someObservable() + "suffix" }".

Comment: no i m talking about the name fields created when an element is pushed to the observable array and field is created automatically. i want to control the way name attribute is fomred

Comment: OK- I think that you must be talking about when you have the `uniqueName` binding on an input.  You can write your own binding handler that modifies this behavior.  Search the source for 'uniqueName', take a copy of that code, modify the name to your own, and alter the behavior for how you want the name generated.  Is this what you are talking about?  Thanks!

Comment: yes RP i m exactly taking about this. actually i want fields to be rendered using knockout but posted the mvc way so we have to provide names to form fields compatible with mvc's conventions. thanks for your valuable input