# can't pass data to controller via ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following model class:

```
[Serializable]
public class SearchHomeModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following controller code:

```
public ActionResult DataTableUserList(SearchHomeModel search, UserListType type, int iDisplayStart, int iDisplayLength, string sEcho)
```

and the following client part:

```
var search = {};
search.FirstName = 'aa';
search.LastName = 'bb';
search.Company = 'kkk';
search.Title = 'aaaawww';

fnServerData: function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
    aoData.push({ "name": "type", "value": "All" });
    aoData.push({ "name": "search", "value": search });
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        url: sSource,
        data: aoData,
```

but I look at debugger on server-side I see that type="All" (it's correct), but search is null. Why and how to pass data to search object from ajax?

Comment: Showing your model code will be helpful.

Comment: How does `type ="All"` while it's not a `string`? Look in the `Request.Params` see what the controller gets.

Comment: "Showing your model code will be helpful" - added

Answer (score 1):

You may or may not find this useful, but I did this so I could directly pass JSON back and forth from the controller.  I had come across this approach [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036297/submit-json-to-mvc3-action) while playing around with Knockout.js.

I created this attribute

```
  public class FromJsonAttribute : CustomModelBinderAttribute
{
    private readonly static JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    public override IModelBinder GetBinder()
    {
        return new JsonModelBinder();
    }

    private class JsonModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var stringified = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request[bindingContext.ModelName];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringified))
                return null;
            return serializer.Deserialize(stringified, bindingContext.ModelType);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my controller code:

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Gifts([FromJson] List<GiftModel> gifts, [FromJson] string guid)
        {
        }
```